# How to use QuickFix to read secdef.dat file

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to read the static securities definition file from the CME, located at:
ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/fix/Production/secdef.dat.gz

Since they seem to be standard fix messages, I thought I could use QuickFix to help me read them into C# rather than parsing the file myself.  I created a test app that basically does what I want, but I'm having 2 issues:

1) I'm getting a QuickFix exception "Invalid message: Header fields out of order" when forming the message from the string.  If I set the "validate" boolean to false, this message disappears and the constructor succeeds, but may be an indicator for the next issue.

2) Upon calling p.Crack, I'm getting the QuickFix exception "QuickFix.UnsupportedMessageType", but there doesn't seem to be any indication of what the message type is that is supposedly unsupported.

Anyway, maybe QuickFix wasn't intended to be used in this way, but any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using QuickFix;

namespace TestQuickFix
{
    class Program : QuickFix.MessageCracker
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string line;

            Program p = new Program();
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\secdef.dat");

            while (((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && count < 10))
            {
                // ISSUE #1 REQUIRES false 2ND ARG WHEN CREATING THE MESSAGE
                Message m = new Message(line, false); 

                // ISSUE #2 Exception of type 'QuickFix.UnsupportedMessageType' was thrown.
                p.Crack(m, new SessionID("beginString", "senderCompID", "targetCompID"));
            }

            file.Close();

        }

        public void OnMessage(QuickFix.FIX50.SecurityDefinition secDef, SessionID sessionID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(secDef.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UnsupportedTypeException that mean one or more of the objects that passed to the method or it's components are note supported types 

so check what you pass to the method again, read the product you use documentaion you may find something about it

Comment: It's UnsupportedMessageType not UnsupportedTypeException.  I think the MessageType is referring to the FIX version of the message, but I'm pretty sure they are in FIXT.1.1/FIX50 format, which QuickFix supports.  Maybe the tag that supplies that information has been somehow stripped from each line of the file, something I'm going to look into.

Comment: have you tested parsing the messages individually on fix.nowing.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After emailing the QuickFix listserv with this question, I was able to get enough information to get this to work.  Although each line still seems to be malformed for some reason, if I keep validation off, I can get the parser to do exactly what I need it to with the following simplified code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using QuickFix;
using QuickFix.DataDictionary;

namespace TestQuickFix
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int MAX_LINES = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataDictionary dd = new QuickFix.DataDictionary.DataDictionary("fix\\FIX50SP2.xml");   
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\secdef.dat");
            int count = 0; string line;
            while (((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && count++ < MAX_LINES))
            {
                QuickFix.FIX50.SecurityDefinition secDef = new QuickFix.FIX50.SecurityDefinition();
                secDef.FromString(line, false, dd, dd);
                Console.WriteLine(secDef.SecurityDesc);
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The messages seems to be in FIX50sp2 format, supported by QuickFIX. (Please take a look at the tag 1128=9).

http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/5.0.SP2/tagNum_1128.html

BUT every single message seems to be not-well formatted. In the header are missed tag 8 (should be the BeginString), and also the tag 56 (TargetCompID), that are mandatory.

Therefore in order to load a single line in a message you must put the "false" parameter to avoid validation.

I suppose the second error is related to the not-well formatted messages.